# Is it possible to send Push Notification to GCM directly from android app?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to get some information from internet on sending push messages from an android client(app) to directly to GCM without involvement of any application server.
My requirement is to send messages to other android devices (one to one).

I basically wish to mimic the SMS behaviour on phones.Also, i have the UID's of all the devices to send PUSH.

If its possible please point to any tutorial OR in case it isnt, i would like to know any third party servers where i can send push message and then that server sends to GCM.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on Parse.com - [Android push guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/Android). It allows to send push notifications from one device to another. It's pretty easy to install and use.
You can save a device UID in `ParseInstallation` and then target this installation:

**Receiver:**

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.put("uid", "1234567890");
installation.saveInBackground();
```

**Sender:**

```
ParseQuery query = ParseInstallation.getQuery(); 
query.whereEqualTo("uid", "1234567890");    
ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(query);
push.sendPushInBackground();
```

Comment: I dont see any way to send push message to any unique device using Parse.Can you share some code. Thanks

Comment: @Suny Please check an edited answer with code sample.

Comment: i ve found the direct way of doing it via a simple POST request to GCM. Thanks for the Parse way.I'l post as answer, it should help others too.